# Can't start Spring application due to java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.web.club3</groupId>
    <artifactId>Java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.web.club3")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        bean.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(sc);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = sc.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

**TestController.java**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String showForm() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

**Result of running**

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:89)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.log.LogDelegateFactory.getHiddenLog(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/commons/logging/Log;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.<init>(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.<init>(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.<init>(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.createRequestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:311)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Structure of project**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXtS1.png)

Answer (score 2):

According to your stacktrace a logging implementation is missing, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory.html#getHiddenLog-java.lang.Class- for reference.

> Mainly for internal use within the framework with Apache Commons Logging, typically in the form of the spring-jcl bridge but also compatible with other Commons Logging bridges.

Try to add the following dependency to solve your issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you just want a quick start, Spring Boot would be an easier starting point for a MVC Spring [application](https://start.spring.io/).

Comment: Now I don`t have errors, but I my application still doesn't run (Process finished with exit code 0)

Comment: Could you put your application on github? This could be related to how you deploy/start your application.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code. You did not configure any container where your Spring MVC application could run into. This could be Jetty, Tomcat, Undertow or sth. else.

If you would like to follow the manual Spring route, you could package your application as a `war` and the Jetty plugin to your `pom.xml` and run the app with `mvn jetty:run`. This would reveal a missing JDBC configuration wich would your next blocker.

Comment: Find a PR for the changes mentioned above: https://github.com/Natalia1910/JavaClub3/pull/1 You can start the webserver with: `mvn jetty:run` , however as there is no datasource configured the application fails with `Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set` and the webserver will respond with 500er status codes.

Comment: thank you very much)

Answer (score 0):

Following 2 entries worked for me.

```
testCompile(group:'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version:'5.3.21')
testCompile(group:'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jcl', version:'5.3.21')
```